# Laravel binding primitives to an array

Tags: php, laravel

As per the Laravel 5 documentation:

```
$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')
          ->needs('$variableName')
          ->give($value);
```

allows you to bind a single value to a controller.

I want multiple service providers to bind to the same $variableName, but instead of the second provider overriding the first provider's value, is it possible to store both values in an array automatically?

For example:

Provider1:

```
$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')
          ->needs('$variableName')
          ->give('Value 1');
```

Provider2:

```
$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')
          ->needs('$variableName')
          ->give('Value 2');
```

Then, in UserController,

I'd like the result to be:

`var_dump($variableName)` as `['Value 1', 'Value 2']`

Is this possible? And if not, is there a workaround for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Can we see more of these providers and why they need the separation? It would seem as if the providers may not be used correctly in this case, or at least another implementation may be useful - such as tagging.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I am developing a "module" system for my Laravel project. Each module has its own provider and I was going to use this method (above) to allow separate modules to send information to each other. For example, lets say a media module and a news module both want to send some information to a controller in the page module, then the page module would receive the information from both modules in an array.

Comment: I'm new to using service providers so my method may not have been the best!

Answer (score 1):

One way to tackle your problem would be to use the `taggable` method; for instance, in one provider, you may want to provide some information about the user:

```
$this->app->bind('UserActivity', function(){
    //whatever you need to do  
});
```

Then later, in another provider, you need to know about something else:

```
$this->app->bind('UserOrders', function() {
    //again, whatever you need to do
});
```

Now in our `FinalImplementationProvider` (the last provider that we will execute to aggregate all of our data from our previously instantiated providers of our container), we can tag all of these:

```
$this->app->tag(['UserOrders', 'UserActivity'], 'userVariables');
```

Finally, we can aggregate all of this data and pass it to a `UserVariableRepository`:

```
$this->app->bind('UserVariableRepository', function($app) {
    return new UserVariableRepository($app->tagged('userVariables'));
});
```

Now your `UserVariableRepository` will be available to you from anywhere and will have access to all the variables you set within the provider instantiations throughout your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a nice approach! However I'd change the final step so that instead of finding a global UserVariableRepository, I'd bind an instance of that class to a variable (as I approached in the question) which would work (i'd prefer the sent data to be attached only to the place it is being sent rather than being globally accessible).

Comment: One problem I did think about though is that when you tag ($this->app->tag(['UserOrders', 'UserActivity'])... , I wouldn't be able to aggregate these names since new modules can be added and also request to be used in a controller, unless this FinalImplementationProvider is manually modified, so it then goes back to the original question where I'd need a way to automatically append it to an array without calling 'UserOrders',  in the tagging process, for example. The only other option I can think of is to use a static variable in the controller which i can push directly to.